# Uploading Usage file in Recommendations-Portal fails

Tags: file-upload, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying the Recommendations API for the first time, in my URL: https://recommendations-portal.azurewebsites.net/... I was able to successfully upload an xlsx file for the Catalog.

For the Usage files however, I tried both xlsx and csv files, but I always get a variation of this error:

```
{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"(EXT-0108) Passed argument is 
invalid.","innerError":{"code":"EXT-0039","message":"'5,135' errors detected 
in the first '5,135' lines of the file"}}}
```

Sample of my data:
2 1 2014-02-28T09:46:16 Purchase
2 1 2014-03-03T01:35:54 Purchase
5 1 2014-03-12T11:08:29 Purchase
7 1 2014-03-12T12:58:58 Purchase
6 1 2014-03-12T13:14:45 Purchase
6 1 2014-03-12T13:23:07 Purchase
6 1 2014-03-12T13:25:36 Purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Recommendations solution should not work with XLSX files for the catalog, only comma separated value (CSV) files that meet the format described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-recommendations-collecting-data

Please make sure to create a new model, and upload the data in the expected format. Something like:

> AAA04294,Office Language Pack Online DwnLd,Office
>
> AAA04303,Minecraft Download Game,Games
>
> C9F00168,Kiruna Flip Cover,Accessories

Then upload your usage files in the expected format. Something like:

> 2,1,2014/03/03T01:35:54,Purchase
>
> 5,1,2014/03/12T11:08:29,Purchase
>
> 7,1,2014/03/12T12:58:58,Purchase

Please make sure that the items referenced in your usage file are actually defined in your catalog file. Also make sure to use real transaction data if possible.

All, in all, please read this document: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-recommendations-collecting-data

Thanks,

Luis Cabrera

Recommendations API Program Manager.

Comment: Thanks for replying here as well. For consistency:

Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. What I had to do was re-upload my Catalog file which was originally an xlsx file and used a csv file instead. Then I re-uploaded my csv Usage file and it worked!